# MySQL returning all matches from a table and indicating if an id is on another table

Tags: mysql, select

**How can I return, on a select, a field that indicates that an id was found?**

My goal is to return all songs(song) from a specific source(source) checking if an user(user) has it or not (user_song).

The query I made almost works. If I remove 'hasSong' (which Im trying to indicate that an user has a song or not), I can see all songs.

[image]

If I keep 'hasSong', I see all songs repeating the song for each user.
[image]

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(song.id) AS id_song, CONCAT(song.article, ' ', song.name) AS name
FROM `song` 
LEFT JOIN `user_song` ON `song`.`id` = `user_song`.`id_song` 
LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id` = `user_song`.`id_user` 
JOIN `song_source` ON `song`.`id` = `song_source`.`id_song` 
WHERE `song_source`.`id_source` = '1' 
    AND ( `user_song`.`id_user` = '3' OR song.id = song_source.id_song ) 
ORDER BY `song`.`name` ASC
```

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `song` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `shortname` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `artist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `genre` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `song_source` (
  `id_song` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_source` int(11) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `source` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_song` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_song` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: what' s your question  .. ?

Comment: "checking if an user(user) has it or not (user_song)." Multiple users may have the same song. So what do you really want to check?

Comment: add   the expected  result

Comment: ı have read your question 3 times and I still have no clue what you want and your question.

Comment: me  ...  too ..  ...

Comment: my question is in BOLD. I want to return all songs for a source, from an user... even if the user does not have that song.... and if the user has a song.... return something that indicates it

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a keyword in the SELECT list, not a function. The parens around (song_id) are superfluous, have no meaning, don't influence the behavior. The only rationale that I can see for that is to mislead someone to believe that DISTINCT is a function, and that's not a good reason to add parens.

Comment: Hi Spencer, without distinct i get way more results. Maybe when i get the correct sql... i will not need distinct

Comment: Why are there no PRIMARY or UNIQUE keys in any of the tables? We should be able to uniquely identify every entity in our system. The absence of a unique identifier is going to unnecessarily complicate the queries. It's valid to use the DISTINCT keyword... what's not valid is disguising it to look like a function. (In the SELECT list, DISTINCT applies to the entire set of expressions, not just something wrapped in parens.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification isn't entirely clear, ...

To return all songs (with no repeated values of `song.id`) that are from a particular source (`id_source='1'`),

along with an indicator, a value of 0 or 1, that tells us if there's a row in `user_song` that matches on `id_song` and is related to a particular user,(`id_user = '3'`)

something like this:

```
SELECT s.id                                AS id_song
     , MAX( CONCAT(s.article,' ',s.name) ) AS name
     , MAX( IF(us.id_user = '3' ,1,0)    ) AS has_song
  FROM `song` s
  JOIN `song_source` ss 
    ON ss.id_song = s.id
   AND ss.id_source = '1'
  LEFT
  JOIN `user_song` us
    ON us.id_song = s.id
   AND us.id_user = '3'
 GROUP BY s.id
 ORDER BY MAX(s.name)
```

---

There are a couple of other query patterns that will return an equivalent result. For example, we could use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list.

```
SELECT s.id                                AS id_song
     , MAX( CONCAT(s.article,' ',s.name) ) AS name

     , ( SELECT IF( COUNT(us.id_user) >0,1,0)
           FROM `user_song` us 
          WHERE us.id_song = s.id
            AND us.id_user = '3'
       ) AS has_song

  FROM `song` s
  JOIN `song_source` ss
    ON ss.id_song = s.id
   AND ss.id_source = '1'
 GROUP BY s.id
 ORDER BY MAX(s.name)
```

---

These queries are complicated by the fact that there are no guarantees of uniqueness in any of the tables. If we had guarantees, we could eliminate the need for a `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions.

Please consider adding PRIMARY and/or UNIQUE KEY constraints on the tables, to prevent duplication.  The way the tables are defined, we could add multiple rows to `song` with the same `id` value. (And those could have different `name` values.)

(And the queries would be *much* simpler if we had some guarantees of uniqueness.)

Comment: Hi Spencer, it looks perfect. thank you! I added some keys. no pk, fk yet. Im getting the data from an api, except user_song.